# Issue encountered while trying to keep website private

Tags: php, functions, password

I'm working on a test site, and I was trying to make my site private by redirecting all non logged-in users to the login page by adding the following code to my theme's function.php file:

```
function redirect_user() {
  if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ! is_page(array('login','register','lostpassword','contact-us' ))) {
    $return_url = esc_url( home_url( '/login/' ) );
    wp_redirect( $return_url );
    exit;
  }

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_user' );
```

After some testing, I've encountered an issue while I was trying to reset the password of my test user. After I click the link to reset my password, I'm being redirected to the login page. I'm trying to figure out how I could resolve this.

Since the reset password link is a dynamically generated link, it's not something I could add to my list of pages as shown in the code extract above. I was checking the wordpress documentation and I'm not seeing anything helpful. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a function called `wp_lostpassword_url` - you could try comparing to its value and see if that lets them through.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing a reset password link, I realised that two variables were being passed via $_GET: key and login. I've added the below code to the beginning of my redirect_user() function:

```
if(isset($_GET['key'])  && isset($_GET['login']))
{
return ;
}
```

It didn't fix the issue and i was still being redirected to the login page whenever I click on the reset password link, however when I made the following edit:

```
if(!isset($_GET['key'])  && !isset($_GET['login']))
    {
    return ;
    }
```

It works as intended but I'm confused why.